# Why it does not return to my return path?

Tags: php, email, email-bounces

I am using php, using mail function:

```
$headers =  'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: admin@domain.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: Admin <admin@domain.com>' . "\r\n";

// Return Path - 
$return_path = "bounce@domain.com";

$toUser... (all necessary variables)

if(mail($toUser,$subject,$body,$headers, "-f".$return_path)){
    echo "res=sent";
} else {
    echo "res=error";
    }
```

I tested few emails like, abXXX@kasbkjasbdka.com, 8hgb87@9ndksjc9ne.com

(etc, all invalid, non-existent email addresses)

Why it dont go to my bounce@domain.com????

Answer (score 1):

You should also be able to set the Return-Path using a header on most servers:

```
$headers .= "Return-Path: bounce@domain.com\r\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a space after `-f`. Also, why not use UTF-8 instead of iso-8859-1? Try this:

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: admin@domain.com' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: Admin <admin@domain.com>' . "\r\n";

// Return Path
$return_path = 'bounce@domain.com';

/*
$toUser... (all necessary variables)
*/

if(mail($toUser, $subject, $body, $headers, '-f ' . $return_path)) {
 echo 'res=sent';
} else {
 echo 'res=error';
}
```

Comment: i added space after "-f" and change charset to UTF-8, but it still does not work. I mean, my bounce@domain.com still didnt receive any bounce email. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: can you provide more solution? I have run out of ideas.. Read my code couple of times... It just wont bounce back...

Comment: You don't need the space. The PHP manual example doesn't have a space and if you look at the documentation for sendmail the parameter doesn't need a space. I also just tested it without a space and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It may be caused by the configuration of your sendmail. The *-F* parameter is piped through as a command line attribute, so sendmail needs to be configured to support it.

From [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php):

> The additional___parameters parameter
>   can be used to pass additional flags
>   as command line options to the program
>   configured to be used when sending
>   mail, as defined by the sendmail_path
>   configuration setting. For example,
>   this can be used to set the envelope
>   sender address when using sendmail
>   with the -f sendmail option.

**Edit:** I just saw that [Matthias Bynens'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026263/why-it-does-not-return-to-my-return-path/1026293#1026293) answer is correct, see [this entry](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php#81979)